# Option at top of drop down list in Smarty

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu, smarty

I have a listing of colleges and universities in mySQL. The list populates from a-z in a drop down menu. I would like to put the option **"no school"** at the top of the list, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

We are using Smarty, so it looks like I need to do something to the tpl file. Here is the code that I would like to edit.

```
            <div class="question inner">Area of Study</div>
            <div class="imp">*</div>
            <div class="inp ka3">
        <select id="area_studied">
        <option value="na"></option>
                {foreach from=$area_studied_options item=entry name=foo}
                    {if $smarty.request.area_studied eq $entry}
                        <option value="{$entry.user_option_id}" selected>{$entry.value}</option>
                    {else}
                        <option value="{$entry.user_option_id}">{$entry.value}</option>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
        </select>
               <span class="add" onclick="addOption('area_studied_location','area_studied')"> </span> 
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div id="area_studied_location" class="autopop">
            {foreach from=$smarty.request.area_studied item=entry name=foo}
                <div><input type="checkbox" name="area_studied[]" value="{$entry}" checked> 
                    {foreach from=$area_studied_options item=option name=bar}
                        {if $entry eq $option.user_option_id}{$option.value}{/if}
                    {/foreach}
                </div>
            {/foreach}
            </div>
            <!-- end: area_studied -->
```

Can someone please tell me what I would need to do in-order to add the option 'no school' (which is already in mysql) to the top of the list?

Answer (score 0):

You say that the 'no school' option already is in your MySQL, all you want is to have it returned as the first row. Then you could change your MySQL query a little bit: (I'm guessing column names):

```
  ORDER BY name ASC
```

to

```
  ORDER BY name='no school' ASC, name ASC
```

This will return 'no school' first.